# Conectar digital storage spaces Nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, typescript, digitalocean

es que tengo un error varios errores, uno de esos es el siguiente que es siempre al correr el programa me salta este mensaje aun que me sigue dejando usar el programa.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es un error que ya segui las instrucciones pero realmente no da una solución que es modificar las librerias de AWS. este es mi codigo de subir una imagen al storage spaces de digital ocean.
codigo:

```
import multer from "multer";
import multerS3 from "multer-s3";
import aws from "aws-sdk";

import { S3, S3Client, PutObjectCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";

const {
  S3_ENDPOINT,
  BUCKET_NAME,
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
}: any = process.env;

const spaceEndpoint: any = new aws.Endpoint(S3_ENDPOINT);

const s3: any = new S3Client({
  endpoint: S3_ENDPOINT,
  forcePathStyle: false, // Configures to use subdomain/virtual calling format.
  region: "fra1",
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  },
});


export const uploadImg:any = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    s3: s3,
    bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
    acl: "public-read",
    metadata: function (req:any, file:any, cb:any) {
      cb(null, { fieldName: file.fieldname });
    },
    key: function (req:any, file:any, cb:any) {
      cb(null, file.originalname);
    },
  }),
}).single("picture");
```

Error:

```
{
    "status": 500,
    "message": "Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: Host: plataya.assets-plataya.fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:*.fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com, DNS:fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com"
}
```